# How to call variable from another function by declaring global in python?

Tags: python, global-variables, global

**func 1**

```
def num1():
    global h
    h=7
```

**func 2**

```
def num2():  
     print(h)
```

When I call this function:

```
num2()
```

Here, it should print the value of `h` which is globally declared in `func 1`. 
But it is giving `NameError` why?? Anyone answer me plz..

Comment: try adding **global h** to the second function

Comment: and another thing: using global variables to share variables between functions is a bad habbit (unless you use them as constant variables such as MAX_VALUE = 100 where you want the max to be the same everywhere. but in this case you don't change its value). a better practice is either pass the variable as a parameter to the functions that use it , or put them both under a class and change this global variable to a class attribute

Comment: You have to actually *call* `num1` for `h` to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

to access the global variable `h` through `num2()` make sure to call `num1()` before calling `num2()`

Answer (score 0):

Defining `num1` doesn't actually define `h`. The definition of `num1` just says that, when you call `num1`, it will assign to the global name `h`. If `h` doesn't exist at that time, it will be created. But *defining* `num1` isn't sufficient to create `h`.

You need to ensure that `h` exists before `num2` is called. You can do that by assigning to `h` yourself, or calling `num1`.

```
>>> num2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in num2
NameError: name 'h' is not defined
>>> h = 3
>>> num2()
3
>>> del h
>>> num2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in num2
NameError: name 'h' is not defined
>>> num1()
>>> num2()
7
```